# Spring Generate Webservice Endpoint URL

Tags: spring, endpoint, xerces

Using JDeveloper, I generated a web service proxy to call methods in an exposed web service. JDeveloper generates request and response classes. In the main method of the proxy client I write the following code:

```
 proxyClient newClient = new proxyClient();
 sampleRequest req = new sampleRequest();
 req.SetDob("10/18/1979");
 req.setSsn("123121234");
 sampleResponse resp = newClient.ProcessDOBandSSN(req);
 System.out.println(resp.getReturnCode());
```

For this I get a `NullPointerException` with just 3 lines of details in my stacktrace.

Now, I've created a second client. This one based on Xerces library. This takes an endpoint URL as a parameter. Whenever I run an endpoint where the endpoint URL has an extension such as `.svc` or `.asmx` then the service runs like charm. However when I try to run Spring based endpoints were not extension is at the end of the URL then I get a file not found exception.

How to address this?